# Numpy slice up to given tensor

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Is there a way to avoid the explicit splitting with the indexes array? I have try to look at `np.s_` but cannot come up with a solution

MWE:

```py
a = np.random.rand(3, 4, 5)
idx = np.array([2, 2, 3])
expected_result = a[:idx[0], :idx[1], :idx[2]]

a[:idx]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first answer:

```
a[tuple([slice(0, id) for id in idx])]
```

Note that `a[[slice(0, id) for id in idx]]` works with the following FutureWarning with `np.__version__ = 1.19.4`:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated;
use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`.
In the future this will be interpreted as an array index,
`arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result
```